# Where can I find detailed documentation of eclipse run parameters?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

[Prevent E4 From Restoring Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097034/prevent-e4-from-restoring-views)

hi greg-449 , I can't add comments to your reply....So I posted this question

**my question is**

> -persistState false

[The Eclipse runtime options](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html&cp%3D2_1_6_0) This parameter is not explained in the document

How do you know this parameter ? Can you share some detailed reference documents ?

Comment: [Here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/FAQ#I_modified_my_App.e4xmi.2Ffragment.e4xmi_but_the_changes_aren.27t_being_loaded._Why.3F) and [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/FAQ#How_can_I_prevent_my_workbench_model_from_being_saved_on_exit.3F).

Comment: There isn't any really detailed documentation other than the actual source code.